# Swift : Pull down to dismiss `UITableViewController`

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to pull down to dismiss `UITableViewController` so I used `scrollViewDidScroll` method but it didn't works!

```
    class CommentViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

        private let tableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 350.0



extension CommentViewController
{
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {



            // Pull down to dismiss TVC 
            let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let adjustment: CGFloat = 130.0

            // for later use
            if (-offsetY) > (tableHeaderHeight+adjustment) {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
 }
    }
```

Comment: Please check if you have set the delegate to your table view.

Comment: tableview already have `UIScrollViewDelegate` right ? if I add it it will cause an error redundant conformance of ... to protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: I mean tableView.delegate set to self?

Comment: i did but still not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to implement additional pan gesture recognizer which will recognize simultaneously with scrollView's pan gesture recognizer. Then you can determine whether user is panning by his finger when table view is already scrolled to the top.
e.g.

```
var isTrackingPanLocation = false
var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.bounces = false
    panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                                                  action: #selector(panRecognized(gestureRecognizer:)))
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

public func panRecognized(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began && tableView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, inView : tableView)

        isTrackingPanLocation = true
    } else if recognizer.state != .ended && 
              recognizer.state != .cancelled && 
              recognizer.state != .failed && 
              isTrackingPanLocation {
        let panOffset = recognizer.translationInView(tableView)

        // determine offset of the pan from the start here. 
        // When offset is far enough from table view top edge - 
        // dismiss your view controller. Additionally you can 
        // determine if pan goes in the wrong direction and 
        // then reset flag isTrackingPanLocation to false

        let eligiblePanOffset = panOffset.y > 200
        if eligiblePanOffset {
            recognizer.enabled = false
            recognizer.enabled = true
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        if panOffset.y < 0 {
            isTrackingPanLocation = false
        }
    } else {
        isTrackingPanLocation = false
    }
}

public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer 
                    otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is eligiblePanOffset ?

Comment: That is a flag which is true when user pulled enough to the top. You have to compute it basing on panOffset and 0 - point of table view bounds. E.g. let eligiblePanOffset = (panOffset.y <= -300)

Comment: I don't know how can you an example

Comment: Crashed After scrolling `panRecognized:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa29b02a770`

Comment: maybe because it's private. Set to public. Let's move to chat conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95635/discussion-between-disabler-and-marrioa).

Comment: After doing this tableview doesn’t scroll anymore

Comment: Check if the method `gestureRecognizer (shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: otherGestureRecognizer:)` is being called for you. I put it there to ensure that the effect that you described doesn't happen.

Comment: it disable tableview scrolling

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 4**

```
var panGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    mainTableView.bounces = true
    panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panRecognized))
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    mainTableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}


@objc func panRecognized(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began && mainTableView.contentOffset.y == 0 {

    } else if recognizer.state != .ended && recognizer.state != .cancelled && recognizer.state != .failed {
        let panOffset = recognizer.translation(in: mainTableView)
        let eligiblePanOffset = panOffset.y > 300
        if eligiblePanOffset {
            recognizer.isEnabled = false
            recognizer.isEnabled = true
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Pretty much interchangeable with UIScrollView as well. This solution is much simpler than others I've seen.

Comment: yea, can use with UIScrollView at the same time :) Thanks

Comment: Cleanest solution on here. Worked out of the box.

Comment: best solution, thx

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you place print(offsetY) in scrollViewDidScroll. I suspect that `(-offsetY) > (tableHeaderHeight+adjustment)` will never be satisfied because of the rubber banding will cause the tableview to rebound before it can dismiss the view controller

Comment: So I should delete it ? what do you suggest ?

Comment: place print(-offsetY) in the scrollViewDidScroll before the if statement. build and run your app, pull down on your tableview, look at the values in the console. Do they ever become greater than 480.0?

Comment: 346.666666666667   this is the result

Comment: So you need to rethink (-offsetY) > (tableHeaderHeight+adjustment) try (-offsetY)> 340.0

Answer (score 2):

For people looking at this in 2019 -- A more modern approach would use the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate) methods, instead of keeping extra state in your view controller. For example:

```
private weak var panFromTop: UIPanGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add pan gesture recognizer
    let panFromTop = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanFromTop(_:)))
    panFromTop.delegate = self
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(panFromTop)
    self.panFromTop = panFromTop
}

@objc func handlePanFromTop(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        // TODO: BEGIN YOUR ANIMATION HERE
    case .changed:
        // TODO: UPDATE YOUR ANIMATION HERE
    default:
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: view)
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view)
        if ((translation.y + velocity.y) / view.bounds.height) > 0.5 {
            // TODO: FINISH YOUR ANIMATION HERE
        } else {
            // TODO: CANCEL YOUR ANIMATION HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Disable bounce at the top of the table view only:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Then implement the gesture recognizer delegate methods:

```
func gestureRecognizer(
    _ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer
) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    guard let recognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer,
        recognizer === panFromTop else {
        // Only require special conditions for the panFromTop gesture recognizer
        return true
    }

    // Require the scroll view to be at the top,
    // and require the pan to start by dragging downward
    return (
        tableView.contentOffset.y <= 0 &&
        recognizer.velocity(in: view).y > 0
    )
}
```

Comment: If you want to scroll up, you need to drag down a little then drag up.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for it! To improve it, don't implement `scrollViewDidScroll` but add `scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false` to `case .began` and `true` to `default` in `handlePanFromTop`.